# Help With Method Increment A Score

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a class that increments a custom field on the Contact record. If the contact has a campaign member status of Opened then the `Pardot_Emails_Opened__c` field increases by 1. If the status is Clicked then the `Pardot_Emails_Opened__c` field and the `Pardot_Links_Clicked__c` field should both be incremented.

The method to update the Email opens is working fine. But the click method is not doing anything. I am a little stumped as they are basically the same code. It does not work in the UI or in my test classes. My code coverage and `System.debug` statements show that nothing is being returned from the `getContacts()` method.

Any help teaching me why one is working and one is not would be appreciated.

```
public without sharing class CampaignMemberUtils {

    public static void   main(List<CampaignMember> newList, Map<Id, CampaignMember> oldList){
        //if the contact status has changed and is opened or clicked call score method

        Set<Id> contactOpenIds  = new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id> contactClickedIds = new Set<Id>();

        for (CampaignMember c : newList){
            CampaignMember oldMember = oldList.get(c.Id);
            System.debug('Email status is :' + c.Status);
            if (c.Status == 'Opened' && oldMember.Status != 'Opened'){
                contactOpenIds.add(c.ContactId);
            }if(c.Status == 'Clicked' && oldMember.Status != 'Clicked'){
                System.debug('Current member status = ' + c.Status);
                System.debug('Old Member status = ' + oldMember.Status);
                contactClickedIds.add(c.Id);
                System.debug('contactClickedIds.size() ' + contactClickedIds.size());
            }
        }
        if(!contactOpenIds.isEmpty()){
            List<Contact> contacts = getContacts(contactOpenIds);
            updateContactOpenScores(contacts);
        }
        if(!contactClickedIds.isEmpty()){
            List<Contact> contacts = getContacts(contactClickedIds);
            updateContactClickedScores(contacts);
        }
    }
    public static void updateContactOpenScores(List<Contact> contacts){
            System.debug('Number of contacts passed to update open score method = ' + contacts.size());
            List<Contact> contactsToUpdate = new List<Contact>();
            for(Contact c : contacts){
                c.Pardot_Emails_Opened__c  +=1;
                contactsToUpdate.add(c);
            }
            update contactsToUpdate;
        }
    public static void updateContactClickedScores(List<Contact>contacts){
        System.debug('Number of contacts passed to update click score ' + contacts.size());

        List<Contact> contactsToUpdate = new List<Contact>();
        for (Contact c : contacts){
            c.Pardot_Emails_Opened__c +=1;
            c.Pardot_Links_Clicked__c +=1;
            contactsToUpdate.add(c);
        }
        update contactsToUpdate;
    }
    public static List<Contact> getContacts(Set<Id> ids) {
        List<Contact> contacts = [
                SELECT Id, Pardot_Emails_Opened__c, Pardot_Links_Clicked__c
                FROM Contact
                WHERE Id = :ids
        ];
        return contacts;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Brooks, please take a moment to revisit the [tour] and [ask]. Please note that if you post a `Question`, you should *ask something*. So *"Any help appreciated"* is not really the correct way to put it. You should instead *ask* *"Why does..."* or *"How do I..."*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant part of your code here is this:

```
if (c.Status == 'Opened' && oldMember.Status != 'Opened'){
    contactOpenIds.add(c.ContactId);
}if(c.Status == 'Clicked' && oldMember.Status != 'Clicked'){
    System.debug('Current member status = ' + c.Status);
    System.debug('Old Member status = ' + oldMember.Status);
    contactClickedIds.add(c.Id);
    System.debug('contactClickedIds.size() ' + contactClickedIds.size());
}
```

The main difference between those two if blocks is that in the "Opened" block, you're adding `c.ContactId` whereas in the "Clicked" block, you're adding `c.Id` (the Id of the `CampaignMember`)

`CampaignMember` is not a `Contact`, which is why your query on `Contact` is returning no rows.

This might be a lesson in why meaningful variable names are impoartant.